# C program to perform a pipe on three commands

Tags: c, command, pipe, fork, ansi-c

I have to write a program that will perform the same operation that **du | sort | head** in the command line would do, but I'm stuck, and my program is not working.  The output right now is *112   .* and the program doesn't terminate. Please help, I don't know what to do!

```
int main(void) {

int fd[2];
int fd1[2];
int pid;

if (pipe(fd) == -1) {
    perror("Pipe");
    exit(1);
}

switch (fork()) {
 case -1:
    perror("Fork");
    exit(2);
 case 0:            
    dup2(fd[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
    close(fd[0]);
    close(fd[1]);
    execl("/usr/bin/du", "du", (char *) 0);
    exit(3);
}
if (pipe(fd1) == -1) {
    perror("Pipe");
    exit(1);
} 

switch (fork()) {
 case -1:
    perror("Fork");
    exit(2);
 case 0:    
    dup2(fd[0], STDIN_FILENO);
    dup2(fd1[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
    close(fd[0]);
    close(fd[1]);
    close(fd1[0]);
    close(fd1[1]);
    execl("/usr/bin/sort", "sort", (char *) 0);
    exit(3);
}

close(fd[0]);
close(fd[1]);

switch (fork()) {
 case -1:
    perror("Fork");
    exit(2);
 case 0:    
    dup2(fd1[0], STDIN_FILENO);
    close(fd1[0]);
    close(fd1[1]);
    execl("/usr/bin/head", "head", (char *) 0);
    exit(3);
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let **head** be your *parent process*, **sort** — its *child process*, and **du** — the *child of **sort***, or the *grandchild of **head***.

You need two pipes, thus, two arrays — fd and fd1. Let the fd pipe connect **sort** with **head**, and fd1 — **du** with **sort**.

You will need one big switch statement, which will determine whether you currently are in the parent process (**head**, pipe(fd) is not 0) or the child (**sort**, pipe(fd) is 0). If you are in **sort**, you need to create the fd1 pipe and run the *grandchild process **du***. Now, since you again have two processes (three in total), you need to set a pipe according to your location — whether you are in the grandchild or the child process. You can use a similar switch statement as you did for pipe fd. The trick here is to set the input and output for fd1 pipe correctly.

Your code must do something like this:

```
int main(void) {

    int fd[2];             // sort <===> head
    int fd1[2];            //  du  <===> sort

    pipe(fd);

    switch (fork()) {
        case 0:            // Are we in sort?
             pipe(fd1);    // If yes, let's make a new pipe!

             switch (fork()) {
                 case 0:   // Are we in du?
                     dup2(fd1[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
                     close(fd1[0]);
                     close(fd1[1]);
                     execl("/usr/bin/du", "du", (whatever directory), NULL);
                     exit(1);

                 default:
                     /* If not in du, we're in sort! in the middle!
                        Let's set up both input and output properly.
                        We have to deal with both pipes */
                     dup2(fd1[0], STDIN_FILENO);
                     dup2(fd[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
                     close(fd1[0]);
                     close(fd1[1]);
                     execl("/usr/bin/sort", "sort (flags if needed)", (char *) 0);
                     exit(2);
             }

            exit(3);

        default:            // If we're not in sort, we're in head
            dup2(fd[0], STDIN_FILENO);
            close(fd[0]);
            close(fd[1]);
            execl("/usr/bin/head", "head (flags if needed)", (char *) 0);
            exit(4);

    }   
}
```